# PHP does a subsequently required file have access to previous requirements?

Tags: php, class, require, mailgun

If I `require` a file, say a Composer autoload script, can a file I subsequently `require`, access the 'contents' of that file? 
I've never had a problem with this before but I seem to be running up against a brick wall.

Loading script:

```
//load required class files
require "../server/frameworks/vendor/autoload.php";
//alias
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
//get config
require "../server/sitetools/config.php";
```

config.php

```
class sitetools{
    function __construct(){
        //Instantiate Mailgun
        $this->mg = new Mailgun("API_KEY");
        $this->domain = "domail.tld";
    }
}
```

I then get an error from my `sitetools` class when I try to instantiate it: *Class 'Mailgun\Mailgun' not found*

Comment: You need to add the namespace to `config.php`, not the loading script (if you don't use it there...).

Comment: But surely it should "transfer"?

Comment: No, that could lead to conflicts. For example if multiple packages have a class called `Log` and you'd include all namespaces in the loading script file.

Comment: By the way, you could have your own classes use the composer autoloader as well, then you don't have to include these either. You'd need to use its naming conventions though.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense! I'll look into that as well. Would you mind submitting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the namespace to config.php, not the loading script (if you don't use it there...).

config.php

```
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

class sitetools {
    function __construct(){
        //Instantiate Mailgun
        $this->mg = new Mailgun("API_KEY");
        $this->domain = "domail.tld";
    }
}
```

And by using the same filename for your script and your class, you should be able to use the composer autoloader for your own classes as well (it might require a bit more configuration...).